# Unsolved metavariable for function that has no inhabited arguments

Tags: idris

I am getting an unsolved metavariable for `foo` in the code below:

```
namespace Funs
  data Funs : Type -> Type where
    Nil : Funs a
    (::) : {b : Type} -> (a -> List b) -> Funs (List a) -> Funs (List a)

  data FunPtr : Funs a -> Type -> Type where
    here : FunPtr ((::) {b} _ bs) b
    there : FunPtr bs b -> FunPtr (_ :: bs) b

total foo : FunPtr [] b -> Void
```

How do I convince Idris that `foo` has no valid patterns to match on?

I've tried adding

```
foo f = ?foo
```

and then doing a case split in Emacs on `f` (just to see what might come up), but that just removes the line, leaving `foo` as an unsolved meta.

Comment: But shouldn't it be `total foo : FunPtr Nil b -> Void`?

Comment: @user3237465: no, `[]` is syntax sugar for any nullary constructor called `Nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out all I need to do is enumerate all possible patterns for `foo`'s argument, and then Idris is able to figure out, one by one, that they are un-unifyable with `foo`'s type:

```
foo : FunPtr [] b -> Void
foo here impossible
foo (there _) impossible
```